# recursive filtering of objects from an array with an unknown number of nestings

Tags: javascript

Recently sorry if it's a duplication of someone question. However I can't find solution for my problem.

I have:

1. array from id's

```
[1, 3, 4];
```

2: complex object with unknown levels of nesting:

```
    {
        "item": [
            {
                "item": [
                    {
                        "item": [
                            {
                                "item": [
                                    {
                                        id: 1,
                                        name: "potato"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "item": [
                                    {
                                        id: 2,
                                        name: "tomato"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "item": [
                            {
                                "item": [
                                    {
                                        id: 3,
                                        name: "apple"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "item": [
                                    {
                                        id: 4,
                                        name: "pineapple"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                id: 5,
                                name: "carrot"
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 6,
                        name: "onion"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

How can I recursively filter plain object **without** breaking it structure? If object from `items` array becomes filtered object the `item` array should be empty.

Comment: "item" is quite a strange name for an array of objects. Also it's quite generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a function which either returns a new object if the id of the object matches, or if one of the subitems matches, or otherwise a Symbol meaning "omit this object" (undefined or null would also work):

```
 const omit = Symbol();

 function filter(obj, ids) {
   const item = obj.item
      .map(it => filter(it, ids))
      .filter(it => it !== omit);

   if(item.length || /* check if id is valid */) {
      return { ...obj, item };
   } else {
      return omit;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can't completely understand what does it mean  `/* check if id is valid */`. That is mean it should check is id one of `ids` array ?

Comment: Yeah if the question shows little effort, I usually omit some small pieces from the answer :)

Comment: hm, seems it's not working https://jsfiddle.net/xwkhd57m/
or maybe I missed something

Comment: Yeah, your object structure is not quite consistent, a lot of objects don't have an `.item` property. https://jsfiddle.net/231onp8w/7/

Comment: it's very cool approach. I can not understand how does `omit` works, but it works. thank a lot